# How to change NSString encoding

Tags: ios, encoding, nsstring, nsdata

I have an NSString that looks like this.

> CitroÃƒÂ«n

Which is ASCII for Citron. So in an effort to try and convert this NSString to its correct form like this

```
string = [dict valueForKey:@"WIGMIGDIGFIG"]; //myBadString
NSData *data = [string dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
//sent it back to NSData with ACII encoding
NSString* mystring = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
// put it back into a NSString but with the correct encoding
NSLog(@"%@", mystring);// check result.
```

So I run this through a loop to check all of the strings I have in my array of dictionaries and every single one comes back in the log accept the one string that has CitroÃƒÂ«n in it. It's just left out of the log.

Updated question, does anyone know how to do what I am trying to do? I'm not even sure whether it's possible. All I want to do is fix the string that's already created, but obviously incorrectly encoded.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "left out of the log" -- that string can be placed in a dictionary and logged as well as any other.

Comment: Keep in mind that what you're seeing is dependent on the character set used for displaying, and may not truly reflect what's in the string.  To see what's in the string examine the numeric values of the characters with `characterAtIndex`, eg.

Comment: This makes no sense: `NSString *string = [[NSString alloc] init];`  NSString is invariant, and the subsequent assignment simply overwrites (and leaks) the address of the empty string you created.

Comment: @HotLicks I tried logging both the original NSString and the newly encoded NSString and I have pairs of everything but when it comes to CitroÃƒÂ«n I only have the old NSString and the new NSString just moves onto the next lot of information.. almost like its never placed into the NSString.

Comment: Well, after that transformation I wouldn't be incredibly surprised.  A string that's written as ASCII and then read as UTF8 is likely to not read in correctly, due to 8-bit characters in the stream that are invalid as UTF8.

Comment: (BTW, I hope you're using ARC.  Otherwise you're leaking up the wazoo.)

Comment: Dunno what encoding CitroÃƒÂ«n is (probably foobared and scrambled UTF-8/Latin1), but it ain't ASCII...

Answer (score 1):

I've just tried your example and the problem is with the line:

```
NSData *data = [string dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
```

If I `NSLog` the contents of `data` I get `nil` returned.  This presumably means that "CitroÃƒÂ«n" is not a valid ASCII string to begin with.  If I use `NSUTF8StringEncoding` instead I get data in the `data` object.

My understanding is that the string conversion methods will return `nil` if the string isn't able to be converted using the specified string encoding.

Comment: right.. so I need to figure out what the previous encoding type is/was.

Comment: I just tired using NSUTF8 for when I place it into the NSData object but when I pass it back to a NSString it outputs the same crap. **CitroÃƒÂ«n**

Comment: I think your ASCII is off.  I tried an `NSUTF8StringEncoding - NSASCIIStringEncoding` combination, and it printed `"CitroÃÆÃÂ«n"`

Comment: I figured it out.. apparently when this string is sent to me the UTF8 prefix is left off it..  so thats what I am dealing with I need to figure out how to fix.. but not really sure atm